# Why does dom4j throw InvalidXPathException for a valid XPath only in my test environment?

Tags: java, xpath, easymock, dom4j

I'm working on authoring some unit testing for some code that I've got working in a system, but I'm having problems with `InvalidXPathException`'s being thrown on valid XPaths.

Using `//external|//inline` to extract out certain elements out of a DOM4J document, and it works in production but not in my test environment. There shouldn't be an issue as it's a valid XPath that I've tested outside of the environment.

Any help would be appreciated!

jUnit/Easymock test:

```
@Test
public void testgetDCR_success(){ 
    RequestContext context = EasyMock.createMock(RequestContext.class);
    FileDal dal = EasyMock.createMock(FileDal.class);
    String xmlContent = "<xml>your sample stuff</xml>";
    Document sampleDoc = Dom4jUtils.newDocument(xmlContent);

    InputStream stream = null;
    try {
        stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlContent.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    } catch(IOException e) {
        Assert.fail("Could not open file stream for test.");
    }

    EasyMock.expect(context.getFileDal()).andReturn(dal).anyTimes();
    EasyMock.expect(dal.getRoot()).andReturn("").anyTimes();
    EasyMock.expect(dal.getSeparator()).andReturn('/').anyTimes();
    EasyMock.expect(dal.exists("/some/path")).andReturn(true);
    EasyMock.expect(dal.read("/some/path")).andReturn(xmlContent);

    EasyMock.expect(dal.getStream("some/path")).andReturn(stream);
    EasyMock.replay(context);
    EasyMock.replay(dal);

    Document doc = new DefaultTransformationService().getDCR(context, "some/path");

    Assert.assertEquals(sampleDoc, doc);
}
```

Lead up to the issue:

```
@Override
public Document getDCR(RequestContext context, String relativePath) {
    LOGGER.debug(">> getDCR");

    if (StringUtils.isBlank(relativePath)) {
        LOGGER.error("No origin file path given");
        LOGGER.debug("<< getDCR");
        return null;
    }

    Document dcrDoc = null;
    try {
        dcrDoc = ExternalUtils.readXmlFile(context, relativePath);
    }catch (RuntimeException e){
        LOGGER.error("No DCR found at file path: "+relativePath,e);
        LOGGER.debug("<< getDCR");
        return null;
    }

    if (dcrDoc == null) {
        LOGGER.error("Unable to open xml file: " + relativePath);
        LOGGER.debug("<< getDCR");
        return null;
    }
    LOGGER.debug("<< getDCR");

    Set<String> parsedPaths = new HashSet<String>();
    parsedPaths.add(relativePath);

    return parseData(context, dcrDoc, parsedPaths);
}

private Document parseData(RequestContext context, Document dcr, Set<String> parsedPaths) {
    LOGGER.debug(">> parseData");

    // get all nodes that would be converted.
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Element> elements = dcr.selectNodes("//external|//inline");

    // For each of the nodes present within the document that are of type external or inline
    for (Element element : elements) {
        // process each element in the list of selected elements.
        processElement(context, element, parsedPaths);
    }

    LOGGER.debug("<< parseData");
    return dcr;
}
```

Stack trace:

```
org.dom4j.InvalidXPathException: Invalid XPath expression:      '//external|//inline'. Caused by: org/jaxen/dom4j/Dom4jXPath
at org.dom4j.xpath.DefaultXPath.parse(DefaultXPath.java:362)
at org.dom4j.xpath.DefaultXPath.<init>(DefaultXPath.java:59)
at org.dom4j.DocumentFactory.createXPath(DocumentFactory.java:230)
at org.dom4j.tree.AbstractNode.createXPath(AbstractNode.java:207)
at org.dom4j.tree.AbstractNode.selectNodes(AbstractNode.java:164)
at com.sample.project.service.impl.DefaultTransformationService.parseData(DefaultTransformationService.java:163)
at com.sample.project.service.impl.DefaultTransformationService.getDCR(DefaultTransformationService.java:144)
at com.sample.project.service.impl.DefaultTransformationServiceTest.testgetDCR_success(DefaultTransformationServiceTest.java:84)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: Does `//*[self::external or self::inline]` work around the problem dom4j has with the original form of the XPath?

Comment: Dom4j doesn't have any issues with the xpath itself. It works just fine in production with the given xpath. In the testing environment it falls over with even a basic "//external" path however.

Comment: How can we help, then, without knowing what's different between your production and test environments?    You have to provide a [mcve] that reproduces the problem you're experiencing in your test environment.

Comment: Updated with additional code for context. Gave what code I could without being overly verbose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the DOM4J source code, one can see that the root cause for that exception is not necessarily an invalid XPath expression:

```
protected static XPath parse(String text) {
    try {
        return new Dom4jXPath(text);
    } catch (JaxenException e) {
        throw new InvalidXPathException(text, e.getMessage());
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        throw new InvalidXPathException(text, t);
    }
}
```

And given how the message looks, one can conclude that `Throwable` was catched. From `InvalidXPathException`:

```
public InvalidXPathException(String xpath, Throwable t) {
    super("Invalid XPath expression: '" + xpath 
            + "'. Caused by: " + t.getMessage());
}
```

Unfortunately, DOM4J hides the original exception in this case, but

```
Caused by: org/jaxen/dom4j/Dom4jXPath
```

implies that the original exception is a NoClassDefFoundError.

However, it is strange that that Dom4jXPath cannot be found while JaxenException is obviously found (since they live in the same jar (jaxen)). Anyway, it looks like your classpath is not set up properly.

BTW, the preceding "analysis" is based on DOM4J 1.6.1., so if you use another version YMMV.